# Remove launcher app icon background

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-theme, android-launcher

I've been developing an app to android for a while and I've been trying different devices with multiple screens dimensions and different OSes.

I was testing the app within a Wiko Robby and I've noticed that the app icon had a background added that on previous devices weren't present.

[image]

The right side icon is *owned* by the OS, whilst the left one is mine. The background I would like to remove is that subtle *rounded corner box* background that was added the the background of the icon.

I've been searching and what I want can be achieved by installing 3rd party apps to edit the OS theme, but I don't want to do that, nor asking the users to do so.

Is there anyway I can remove the background?

Comment: It's your phone's launcher that adds those backgrounds, if it allows you to remove them you should find it in the launcher's settings, if you can't, just install another one such as ZenUI

Comment: As I've stated, I'm developing the app. My intent is to remove it somehow, so whenever someone installs it, there's no additional elements to the app icon. I want to avoid ***AT ALL COSTS*** any 3rd party app to modify the OS/Launcher

Comment: You can not do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, unfortunately. This feature is entirely managed by the home screen and developers have no control over it.

I don't think that you should worry about it, though. The user is probably used to see this background behind 3rd party app icons and he will probably not even notice it on your app. I would even argue that it can be disturbing for the user if your icon was displayed without this background, as this could led him to believe that your app is a system app.

Comment: After searching and installing some apps, the background is something that cannot be helped without modifying the icon. One more point to my list of things that I hate about Android...